# Sys.which('make') returns an empty vector, resulting in installation failure of package built with .cpp

Tags: r, rtools

I've already updated r, rtools and rstudio. But it seems unable to find `make.exe`, while in `C:\rtools40\usr\bin\make.exe` it exists.

```
> find_rtools()
[1] TRUE
> Sys.which('make')
make 
  "" 
> R.Version()$version.string
[1] "R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)"
```

Rtools is rtools40-x86_64.exe downloaded from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/.
All packages are up to date (Rstudio told me so).

And when I'm trying to install a package built with Rcpp, it returns

```
Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'testpkg'
```

and the installation fails. Is there any way I can deal with it?

Comment: Well, probably an issue with your PATH. Check `Sys.getenv("PATH")`. Does it include `C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin`? If not, add it to the PATH. See this documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: Oh that works. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: but this works only for that specific session. How can I set it permanently?