# Sys.which("make") empty although Rtools is in PATH

Tags: r, rtools

I have completely uninstalled R, RStudio, and RTools and removed all folders (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61187094/8839068)); then re-installed R (4.0.4), RTools (4.0 x86), and RStudio (1.4.1106). I have added the RTools folder to the path (`Sys.getenv("PATH") # [1] "$C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin;...."`) but the problem persists - 'make' is empty, although `C:\rtools40\usr\bin\make.exe` exists:

```
> Sys.which("make")
make 
  ""
```

Can someone help me? ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65068785/sys-whichmake-returns-an-empty-vector-resulting-in-installation-failure-of) question didn't help, since my PATH variable contains the RTools folder already.)

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: Is there a reason the `PATH` starts with `$C:` instead of just `C:`?

Comment: Test this with `Sys.setenv(PATH=gsub("^\\$", "", Sys.getenv("PATH")))`, and then `Sys.which("make")`. If that works, make sure you fix where that mistake is entered (such as the *Environment Variables* control for windows).

Comment: Additionally, how do I set the path permanently? It vanishes after I restart R (despite appending the Rtools path to PATH variable - `Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(old_path, "C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin\\", sep = ";"))`

Comment: @r2evans - can help me please? While the above command sets the Rtools path to the path variable, it vanishes after I restart the RGUI

Comment: Since this works, I suggested that you fix it in a more proper place, wherever the environment variables are set for your OS. If windows, go to *Settings* (windows, not R) and look for *Environment Variables*and modify the path there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity: the problem was that the "$" doesn't belong in the path.

Thanks to @r2evans for the solution - `Sys.setenv(PATH=gsub("^\\$", "", Sys.getenv("PATH")))` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution proposed [here](https://github.com/metrumresearchgroup/mrgsolve/issues/160) worked for a single session, then I had to add the paths permanently in the environmental variables settings as suggested by @r2evans.

This is the solution for a single session:

```
path <- Sys.getenv("PATH")
path <- c("C:\\RBuildTools\\3.3\\bin", "C:\\RBuildTools\\3.3\\gcc-4.6.3\\bin", path) 
#Remember to substitute the two paths with your actual paths.
path <- paste(path,collapse=";")

#Then run
Sys.setenv(PATH=path)
Sys.which("make")
```

In both the temporary and permanent solution I had to include the paths at the beginning of PATH, otherwise they were not recognized, but I don't know why.